# How do i make a div stay on top of other div's while scrolling the page?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Pls help me. I've tried.

This is my code presently

HTML

```
    <div id="header"><!--beggining of header-->

    </div><!--end of header-->
```

CSS

```
    #header {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F0F;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

SORRY. THIS IS MY FIRST TIME USING THIS STE. I CANT POST THE CODE.
BUT SEE THE FULL HTML [HERE](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5aAKbasrRdqM0xzVkNMRl9yLUE)

Comment: please post your complete code :-)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what is the problem?

Comment: when i make it fixed? the div hides.

Comment: There must be more HTML than that!

Answer (score 5):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npu3L/)

html:

```
<div class="cover">
  top
   <div class="fixed-box">
     hello                            
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed-box {
  width:100px;/*just for preview*/
  height:100px;/*just for preview*/
  background:red;/*just for preview*/
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
}
.cover {
  width:500px;/*just for preview*/
  height:10000px;/*just for preview*/
  background:blue;/*just for preview*/
}
```

Comment: +1. You can also see the scrolling happen better with this update: http://jsfiddle.net/npu3L/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {width: auto; height: 100px; background-color: #F0F; border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000; position: fixed; top:0px; z-index:100;}
```

please make sure after the header div make one container div for content and make that div `position:relative; z-index:50;`